# Handling Concurrent Product Orders and Quantity Updates Safely in NestJS

Tags: concurrency, transactions, nestjs, locking, typeorm

I'm currently facing a challenge in my NestJS application related to managing concurrent product orders and quantity updates. Below is a simplified version of the code I'm using to create orders:

```
async createOrder(userId: string, products: ProductForOrder[], paymentStatus: PaymentStatusEnum): Promise<OrdersRo> {
    for (const product of products) {
      const foundProduct = await this.productsRepository.findOne({
        where: { id: product.productId },
      });
      if (!foundProduct) {
        throw new HttpException("Product's ID not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      }
      if (foundProduct.unitsOnStock - product.quantity < 0) {
        throw new HttpException(
          `Insufficient stock for product: ${foundProduct.name}`,
          HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        );
      }
    }

    const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({ where: { id: userId } });
    if (!user)
      throw new HttpException("Invalid user's ID", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    const order = await this.ordersRepository.create({ customer: user, paymentStatus });
    await this.ordersRepository.save(order);

    for (const product of products) {
      const foundProduct = await this.productsRepository.findOne({
        where: { id: product.productId },
      });
      await this.productsRepository.update(foundProduct.id, {
        unitsOnStock: foundProduct.unitsOnStock - product.quantity,
      });

      const orderDetails = await this.orderDetailsRepository.create({
        product: foundProduct,
        order,
        quantity: product.quantity,
      });

      await this.orderDetailsRepository.save(orderDetails);
    }
    return this.toResponseOrder(order);
  }
```

In this code, I'm checking the availability of products based on the quantity available in stock before creating an order. However, I'm concerned about potential concurrency issues when multiple users try to place orders for the same product simultaneously. Due to the time gap between the availability check and the actual order creation, it's possible that the available quantity becomes outdated.

I'd like to ask for suggestions on how to handle this scenario effectively. What strategies or approaches can I adopt to ensure that the product availability check and quantity update are performed atomically, preventing any conflicts and inconsistencies when multiple orders are placed simultaneously? Your guidance and insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For read available quantity from stock, you can try read query with setLocking ('pessimistic_write') to make sure the quantity is not be changed before the order be created:

```
stocks = await queryRunner.manager
          .getRepository(Stock)
          .createQueryBuilder("stock")
          .useTransaction(true)
          .setLock("pessimistic_write")
          .where("stock.productId = :id", { id: id })
          .getMany();
```